# 'Cannot be resolved to a type' error with Spring Roo

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-roo

I am trying to learn Spring Roo following the tutorial [Getting Started with Spring Roo](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/05/27/roo-part-2/).

However, when AspectJ files were created Eclipse is now complaining with compile errors.

The only commands for me to get those errors were:

```
mkdir wedding
cd wedding
roo
    project --topLevelPackage com.wedding
import the Maven project into Eclipse
    persistence setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_PERSISTENT
    entity --class ~.domain.Rsvp
```

Now I've an error list with:

```
declare cannot be resolved to a type
entityManager cannot be resolved or is not a field
id cannot be resolved or is not a field
The method entityManager() is undefined for the type Rsvp_Roo_Entity
version cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Anyone also experienced this issue and knows how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you STS and WTP installed in your Eclipse?

Did you tried the following in the Roo console:

```
perform eclipse
```

?

Comment: That should be the solution. Find in the tutorial the "chapter" **IDE Integration** when this command appears: roo> perform eclipse
 and it is said how to import the project into STS-Eclipse: ile > Import > Existing Projects into Workspace

Comment: And be careful with this tutorial. It's excellent but it's out of date regarding the syntax of some roo commands. Try the oones that comes with the Roo distribution, within the samples directory (vote, clinic, and so on)

Comment: @Constantiner. Yes, I've STS, WTP and even the Roo console within Eclipse. Thank you! "perform eclipse" worked and now in fact over the project icon, I've AJ, instead before it was just a Maven project. So I guess the problem was "import maven project". I am wondering If I've to do a "perform eclipse" every time I add some new feature, like JPA.

Comment: @jbbarquero, I tried Import Existing Project into Workspace, but it's not allowed because it's not an eclipse project yet, I can only import as Maven project, or I can "perform eclipse" and after that I can do Import Existing Project. I tried also to create the Roo project directly from Eclipse, but when I choose 'convert to faceted' project, it also displays the same error until I do 'perform eclipse'. So I guess there is no escape from 'perform eclipse'. :-) I will look also the other tutorials. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you only created the project and imported it as existing Maven project you have to:

- Right-click the project > Spring Tools > Enable Roo Project Nature
- Right-click the project > Spring Tools > Enable Spring Aspects Tooling

For me, I was missing the second one and it finally fixed it.